# PHP - Unwanted automatic apt install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04, php

I am working on some local PHP and Laravel development on Ubuntu 22.04. I'm having a problem with PHP 8.1 and Apache2 being automatically installed by `apt`. This ends up taking precedence over the 8.3 version I compiled myself. I don't need or want the 8.1 version, or frankly, the apache2 server (locally at least). I want to only use version 8.3. It seems to be happening when the computer goes into sleep mode, or if it's restarted. I remove all the packages with `apt`, but they just keep coming back. Very frustrating!

The output of `apt list --installed | grep php` is as follows:

```sh
libapache2-mod-php8.1/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php-common/jammy,jammy,now 2:92ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1-common/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1-opcache/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1-readline/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 all [installed,automatic]
php/jammy,jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

and `apt list --installed | grep apache2`

```sh
apache2-bin/jammy-security,now 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8]
apache2-data/jammy-security,jammy-security,now 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7 all [installed,upgradable to: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8]
apache2-utils/jammy-security,now 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8]
apache2/jammy-security,now 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.8]
libapache2-mod-php8.1/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Things I've tried:
I saw other answers in regards to determining why a package is automatically instlled using `aptitude`. I've tried chasing down the culprit package without much success. Things like

```sh
aptitude why libapache2-mod-php8.1
i   php    Depends php8.1                                         
i A php8.1 Depends libapache2-mod-php8.1 | php8.1-fpm | php8.1-cgi

aptitude why php8.1-cli           
i   php                   Depends php8.1                                         
i A php8.1                Depends libapache2-mod-php8.1 | php8.1-fpm | php8.1-cgi
i A libapache2-mod-php8.1 Depends php8.1-cli  

aptitude why php8.1     
i   php Depends php8.1
```

have not been very useful. I've tried removing all of the unwanted packages with `apt`, but they just keep coming back automatically. I obviously don't want to remove these by hand & reinstall my compiled 8.3 version every time I fire up the computer.

I have not tried using a PHP version manager, but at this time, I don't *need* any other versions of PHP. So I haven't gone down that route. I'd rather learn how to discover why this is happening & manage the situation on it's own.

This is above my knowledge of Ubuntu administration, and I'm having trouble searching for any similar problems. Any guidance would be appreciated!.

Comment: Your output shows that the `php` package was selected for install by a human. All the others are simply dependencies of that manually-selected package.

Comment: I see. I compiled version 8.3 myself, then installed `php` using the `checkinstall` tool, versus directly using `make install`. Maybe I should have included that in the original question. Is it possible this method is causing this unwanted behavior from `apt`?

Comment: Your output shows that you installed `php` version 8.1 from the Ubuntu repos. Not locally-compiled `php` (or a different name) version 8.3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that now, but I assure you I've never installed `php` using `apt`. This is a clean, minimal Ubuntu install.Here is the output after I cleaned up the automatic installs and reinstalled my compiled version with checkinstall
`php/now 8.3.4-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2:8.1+92ubuntu1] `
It thinks my php is 'upgradable' to 8.1 which makes no sense obviously. I'm guessing that's a weird quirk of building my own .deb package?

Comment: Now `sudo apt-mark hold php` so your next apt-upgrade doesn't reinstall the Ubuntu `php` package. See https://serverfault.com/questions/604541/debian-packages-version-convention for an explanation of why your package is lower according to Debian rules.